# jQuery animation function not working right

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a simple "go up" and "go down" button like this:

```
var toppos = $(window).scrollTop();

if (toppos > 600) {
    $('.upBtn').addClass('up');
}

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 600) {
        $('.upBtn').addClass('up');
    } else {
        $('.upBtn').removeClass('up');
    }
});

$('.upBtn').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 600}, 800, 'easeInOutCubic');
});

$('.upBtn.up').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0}, 800, 'easeInOutCubic');
});
```

However, only one of the two functions works. If my scrollTop > 600 the button only fires  the one with .up - regardless of whether the class is removed or not. Im confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two main issues with your code. Firstly, both your `click` handlers will fire when the click occurs, leading to a race condition. Attach a single click event handler to move the scroll position based on whether or not the element has the `up` class.

Secondly, you set the `scrollTop` **equal** to `600`, so the `> 600` check will never hit. You need to use `>= 600`.

```js
var topPos = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.upBtn').toggleClass('up', topPos >= 600);

$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.upBtn').toggleClass('up', $(this).scrollTop() >= 600);
});

$('.upBtn').on('click', e => {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(e.target).hasClass('up') ? 0 : 600
  }, 800, 'easeInOutCubic');
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 610px;
}

.upBtn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.4.1/jquery.easing.min.js" integrity="sha512-0QbL0ph8Tc8g5bLhfVzSqxe9GERORsKhIn1IrpxDAgUsbBGz/V7iSav2zzW325XGd1OMLdL4UiqRJj702IeqnQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class="content">
  Scroll down...
</div>
<div class="content">
  Scroll back up...
</div>
<button class="upBtn">Toggle Position</button>
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I surely need to learn more about Javascript.